# Python 2.7- read data from csv and write to Vfp dbf with field names greater than 10 characters long

Tags: python, csv, visual-foxpro, dbf

I'm trying to read rows of data from a csv and append them as records to an existing Visual FoxPro dbf. The existing Visual FoxPro dbf has many fields that are greater than 10 characters long, but this causes an error when using modules dbf or dbfpy.

Here is an example with a simplified version of the table structure:

```
import dbf
table=dbf.from_csv('seasdate.csv',field_names="zone_num   season_code",dbf_type='Vfp')
#table to write to
table2=('temptable','zone_num C(2); season_code C(1)',dbf_type='Vfp')
for datum in table:
    table2.append(datum)
```

This returns: 'dbf.ver_2.FieldSpecError: Maximum field name length is 10.  'season_code' is 11 characters long.'

I know it is possible to have a field name greater than 10 characters long in a Vfp table because, as I mentioned, the table I ultimately will append to already exists. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't remember implementing long field names; can you send me a small dbf with a couple long field names?  I'll see what I can do.  My email is in the package.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I tried sending an email to the address listed in the package and it bounced back.

Comment: It's my first name at stoneleaf dot us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use dbfpy but looking at that syntax, it looks like you are creating new "free" tables. Free tables' fieldNames are limited to 10 in length.

Probably you should look at www.leafe.com and Dabo Framework there. Ed Leafe is from VFP community and he is well aware of VFP database formats.

Comment: I didn't say it does. I only said as I understand code is creating a new free table.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, the field names stored in the `.dbf` file are only 10 characters long -- the first 10, as it happens (I'm not sure if the first 10 characters must be unique, or how VFP handles that, though.)  So if your field names are all unique in the first 10, just use the truncated names:

```
table2=('temptable','zone_num C(2); season_cod C(1)',dbf_type='Vfp')
```

Currently [dbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) does not support the long field names.  If you want to get me a sample VFP `.dbc` with long field names I would be happy to look at adding that support.

Comment: Visual FoxPro supports long column names by storing them as meta-data separately in a in a "DBC" (DataBaseContainer, a renamed DBF). In VFP9, for example, you can `CREATE DATABASE longnames` and then `CREATE TABLE longnames1 (column1integer Int, column2varchar100 varchar(100))`. I can send you binaries if you want.

Comment: @StefanWuebbe: Please do, I no longer have access to VFP.